# the package appears to be corrupt

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

After update android studio 2.3.3 to 3.0, after updating facing new problem apk is not install into mobile after share apk through share or any sharing app. but install in emulator.
also try below things

Try disable instant run.
try clean and rebulid project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow [**`The package appears to be corrupted`**](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-android/issues/177).

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDevDebug
```

If same problem then downgrade **`tools.build:gradle`** version.
 I assume its a bug.

```
 // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

**FYI**

Build your project in **`Release/Signed`** mode. This problem will overcome. Only **`BUILD`** mode creating this issue.

Comment: whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Please go to device setting.
2. Select Apps.
3. Select your specific app.
4. Click on top right corner overflow menu, and click on "**Uninstall
   for All Users**".
   5.Try to install your new signed apk.
5. Hope this will help, I had a same issue, and solved by following
   above steps.